# Add Button to Bounded DataGridColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got this XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SlData" Source="test.xml" XPath="/sls/sl"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgridEmp" Style="{DynamicResource Datag1}" DataContext="{StaticResource SlData}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/sls/sl}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="1,145,7,-506" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="bencd" Binding="{Binding XPath=benCd}" Width="72" >
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="slpos" Binding="{Binding XPath=slpos}" Width="40" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="slNr" Binding="{Binding XPath=slNr}" Width="72" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="stufe" Binding="{Binding XPath=stufe}" Width="40" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="spJn" Binding="{Binding XPath=spJN}" Width="40" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="slNrHpt" Binding="{Binding XPath=slNrHpt}" Width="72" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="me" Binding="{Binding XPath=menge}" Width="30" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="bez" Binding="{Binding XPath=bez}" Width="250" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="bezkurz" Binding="{Binding XPath=bezkurz}" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="bezE" Binding="{Binding XPath=bezE}" Width="100" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What i want is to add a Button Right to Datagridtextcolumn with header "bencd", so that it looks like this (With this blue filter button at right position):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Header` property to any element you want, like for example a `StackPanel` with a `TextBlock` and a `Button`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=benCd}" Width="72" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="bencd"/>
            <Button Content="Filter" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Of course you need to style the `Button` to make it look like a "filter" button but that's another story.